# MySQL error 1248, Creating proper query. Beginner Q

Tags: mysql

I am running into some difficulty with the following query.

```
SELECT maker, speed 
FROM  
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM product 
    NATURAL JOIN laptop
) 
WHERE hd > 30;
```

I am trying to find the maker and speed of laptops with hard drives greater than 30 gigabytes.

I have two relations laptops and products. Laptops has the tuples (maker, model, type) and laptop has the tuples (model, speed, ram, hd, screen, and price).

What I think I am doing.

- Joining product with laptop with natural join, which I think and does
  (when submitted by itself) give me a relation of laptop but with two
  more columns maker and type.
- I then am trying to just select maker and speed from that table where
  the size of the hd is greater than 30.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? If so, please show us the error. Are you receiving a resultset other than what you're expecting? If so, please show us.

Comment: What is the difficulty?  Does your query give an error? What database are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subquery in the `FROM` clause requires a table alias:

```
SELECT maker, speed 
FROM  
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM product 
    NATURAL JOIN laptop
  /* include an alias with AS */
) AS products_sub
WHERE hd > 30;
```

[From the docs:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> A table_subquery is also known as a subquery in the FROM clause. Such subqueries must include an alias to give the subquery result a table name. A trivial example follows; see also Section 12.2.9.8, “Subqueries in the FROM Clause”.

However for your example, the subquery isn't needed at all.

```
SELECT maker, speed 
FROM products NATURAL JOIN laptop
WHERE hd > 30;
```

Note that `NATURAL JOIN`s are not usually recommended, and it is best to be explicit about the columns joined in an `ON` clause.

Comment: The subquery serves no puprose and can be omitted

Comment: +1 for "*natural joins are not usually recommended*". Very good point.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT maker, speed 
  FROM products   JOIN laptop 
  WHERE hd > 30;
```